# How to Simulate tcp server is not responding

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I have to write a code in python language to create a tcp server. Different devices(client) will connect to this server and sends a file of approx 1GB.
The problem is, after receiveing approx 500MB of file, this server should simulate that the TCP connection is broken unexpectedly and it is not responding to client TCP packets with ACK or NACKS. Then the client will retry to setup the connection. Is there a way to do so?? How can I simulate this negative scenario in python v2.7.
Please help!

Comment: You could shutdown and close the connection.

Comment: Are you trying to run this scenario in a programatic test or just manually checking the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how much data has been received by the server by storing the amount in a variable like so:

```
received = 0

# when receiving data:
data = sock.recv(2084)
received += 2084
```

and if this value reaches the desired value, you can simply close the socket using

```
sock.close()
```

This will cause a "Connection Refused" error on the client, which forces the client to set-up a new connection / reconnect the socket to the server.

be aware that, if you are using other values for the `recv()` buffer, you need to change that in your receieve counter as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the suggestions, I will try this and will update with the progress.